# PHP - Delete XML tag Elements based on selected Checkbox Array values

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file of songs and I'm using PHP to build a form (with checkboxes) to delete 1 or more songs from that file. The problem I'm running into is that I can't quite figure out how to iterate through the list of IDs from the form and delete the songs with those IDs.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<songs>
    <song id="1380682359">
        <artist>Artist</artist>
        <title>Title</title>
    </song>
    <song id="1380682374">
        <artist>Artist</artist>
        <title>Title</title>
    </song>
    <song id="1380828782">
        <artist>Artist</artist>
        <title>Title</title>
    </song>
</songs>
```

This builds the form:

```
<?
echo "<form action='removesong.php' method='post'>\n";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('songlist.xml');
$songlist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("song");
foreach($songlist as $song) {
    $id = $song->getAttribute("id");
    $artists = $song->getElementsByTagName("artist");
    $artist = $artists->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $titles = $song->getElementsByTagName("title");
    $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='SongsToRemove[]' value='" . $id . "'> $artist, &quot;$title&quot;<br>\n";
}
echo "<br><input type='submit' value='Delete Song' />\n</form>\n";
?>
```

And "removesong.php" is going to be something close to this (I think):

```
<?
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("songlist.xml");
$songs = $doc->getElementsByTagName("song");
foreach($songs as $song) {
    if($song['id'] == $_POST["SongsToRemove"]) {
        unset($song); // or $song->removeChild($song);
    }
}
$doc->save("songlist.xml");
?>
```

I can't quite figure out how to use $_POST["SongsToRemove"] to delete those songs.

Answer (score 0):

--edit-- just saw you are already using a $_POST array, so modified the example:

try this:

```
<?
// post variable is string with comma seperators
//$_POST['SongsToRemove'] = '1380682359,1380828782';
//$songs_to_remove = explode( ',', $_POST['SongsToRemove'] );

// songs to remove is already post array:
$songs_to_remove = $_POST['SongsToRemove'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("songlist.xml");
$songs = $doc->getElementsByTagName("song");
foreach($songs as $song) {
    if( in_array( $song['id'], $songs_to_remove ) {
        unset($song); // or $song->removeChild($song);
    }
}
$doc->save("songlist.xml");
?>
```

Other things you could try are setting the songs to remove to an array (you can do that with HTML too): this would eliminate the need for the explode etc...

```
<input type="text" name="SongsToRemove[]" />
<input type="text" name="SongsToRemove[]" />
<input type="text" name="SongsToRemove[]" />
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and it gave me this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array in /home/nolan/public_html/_RCF/prayer_new/removesong.php

Comment: Try using the removeChild() in your commented line next to unset($song) like this: $songs->removeChild($song); (note the songs/song)

Comment: I tried, but it throws me an error on the line before that one, (on the "if in_array" line): Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array